# Cant remove a setted active Element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

currently i working on a Sorting Script for a Database. I will filter my Database with a Filtermenu, the Options will be displayed as Link, after i click on a Link, i do an Ajax Request via jQuery to Filter the Results and reload the Filtermenu. This works all Fine.

But i have a little Problem with removing of a Filter .. sometimes, when i click on the X, it removes the Filter fine, but sometimes, i must click 3 or 4 times, to remove the Filter.

My jQuery Code is:

```
// Doing set Filter
$('.figurelib-sorting').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data('id'));
    figurelib_handleFilters();
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Doing remove Filter
$('.figurelib-sorting').on('click', 'a.remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
    figurelib_handleFilters();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My HTML-Markup when there is no Filter setted:

```
<div id="figurelib-sorting-brands" class="figurelib-sorting">
  <div class="side-label">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> Brands
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-wrapper scrollbar-inner scrollbar-inner-brands" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="scrollbar-inner scrollbar-inner-brands scroll-content" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; max-height: 40px;">
      <input type="hidden" id="figurelib_sorting_brand" value="0">
      <a href="#" title="Alien (1979)" data-id="1">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> Alien (1979)
        <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">2</span>
      </a><br>
      <a href="#" title="Aliens (1986)" data-id="2">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> Aliens (1986)
        <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">1</span>
      </a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My HTML-Markup when there is a Filter setted:

```
<div id="figurelib-sorting-brands" class="figurelib-sorting">
  <div class="side-label">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> Brands
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-wrapper scrollbar-inner scrollbar-inner-brands" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="scrollbar-inner scrollbar-inner-brands scroll-content" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; max-height: 38px;">
      <input type="hidden" id="figurelib_sorting_brand" value="1">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i> <strong>Alien (1979)</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" title="Remove Brand Filter" class="remove">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times text-danger"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
      <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">2</span><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note, i have more than 1 Filter, all called with the same jQuery Script, all have same HTML-Markup (expect the DIV-ID).

Thanks for Help, greets ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `remove` class is set, *both* handlers will run. If you only want to run the `set` filter when there's no `remove` class, you need to check for that. Change it to:

```
// Doing set Filter
$('.figurelib-sorting').on('click', 'a:not(.remove)', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data('id'));
    figurelib_handleFilters();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Another way to do it is with a single handler that checks whether the `remove` class is set:

```
$('.figurelib-sorting').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("remove")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data('id'));
    }
    figurelib_handleFilters();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I take the second variante, because it will make the Code smaller .. Thanks :)